# exception in string comparison with empty string

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I'm new in the c# programming. I was trying to make a calculator and i wanted to include backspace in it. I have a problem with an if statement that doesnt work.
Here is my code

```
    if ((result.Text != "0")||(result.Text.Length>0))
        {
            result.Text = result.Text.Remove(result.Text.Length - 1);
        }
```

result is the name of the textField that i created in Visual Studio. Basically i want if the text is not 0 or the length of the result.text is greater that 0 (so it's not empty string) to delete the last caracter of the result.text. For some reason the conditions of the if statement are not working and in the end it throws me an exception "***An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll***".

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the `||` operator, it should be `&&`:

```
  if ((result.Text != "0") && (result.Text.Length>0))
```

The better check, however is

```
  if ((result.Text != "0") && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text)))
    ...
```

which help you out if `result.Text == null`

Comment: As in, use a logical AND (`&&`) not a logical OR (`||`), because you want the string in your `TextField` instance to not equal "0" AND(!!!) to be more than 0 characters long. I suggest you read up on C#'s logical operators [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) (as your current knowledge seems to be lacking) - this is a must for writing nice and clean conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using an || (or) instead of an && (and). Try the following:

```
if ((result.Text != "0")&&(result.Text.Length>0))
    {
        result.Text = result.Text.Remove(result.Text.Length - 1);
    }
```